# Noção Big O e small O, Big Omega e Small Omega, aplicado a funções exponenciais muito parecidas

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

No livro acadêmico que utilizamos, pede para relacionarmos o que uma função A é de uma função B (ex: `A = O(B)`)

Tem uma relação que não consigo entender a resolução da resposta

A = `(1,21)^n`

B = `(1,2)^n`

Pra mim, a relação entre os dois seria que `A = ω(B) e Ω(B)`, visto que `A > B` pra todo `n > 0`, ou seja, `A` jamais vai assumir valores abaixo dos de `B`

Mas a resolução do livro demonstra por limite, faz o `limite(A/B) com n indo ao infinito`. O resultado é infinito, dai ele deduz disso que `B` é insignificante comparado a `A` para `n = infinito`.

O problema é que, se eu inverter o limite ali, e fizer `limite(B/A) com n tendendo a infinito` a resposta também é infinito, de maneira que isso serviria pros dois lados.

Isso me deixou na dúvida com relação a como raciocinar esse tipo de problema, como eu demonstro que o limite ali só serve pra um dos casos e não pros dois, mesmo que invertendo denominador e expoente da na mesma?